# How to fix 'Type is missing properties from type' with generic object?

Tags: typescript, incompatibletypeerror

Consider a library which exports a `run` function like below:

**`runner.ts`**

```js
export type Parameters = { [key: string]: string };
type runner = (args: Parameters) => void;

export default function run(fn: runner, params: Parameters) {
    fn(params);
}
```

And consider the following code in a separate file:
**`index.ts`**

```js
import type { Parameters } from "./runner.ts";
import run from "./runner.ts";

type CustomParams = { hello: string };

function logGenericArgs(args: Parameters): void {
    console.log(args);
}

function logHelloFromArgs(args: CustomParams): void {
    console.log(args.hello);
}

run(logGenericArgs, { abc: "123" });
run(logHelloFromArgs, { hello: "123" });  /* Argument of type '(args: CustomParams) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'runner'.
  Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Property 'hello' is missing in type 'Parameters' but required in type 'CustomParams'. ts(2345)
*/
```

Why does TypeScript complain about the different types, when they're perfectly compatible with each other? From my understanding, type `Parameters` is a generic object with `string` keys and `string` values; `CustomParams`'s "hello" key perfectly fits the `Parameters`'s type signature.

How can I make the code in the "runner" library to accept a generic object type, and work nicely with other types that are compatible?
I do not want to use type `unknown` or `any`, as that's basically useless. I want the call signature of the `run` function to express that `args` is an object, but I do not want to limit the `args`' type to that specific signature only.
I also do not want to specify the `hello` key in type `CustomParams` as optional, because that key should not be optional in the usage of the type `CustomParams` - and I do not want to add the key `hello` in type `Parameters` because it is not required in every use case of the "runner" library.

Comment: Your runner library makes no guarantees through the type system that the arguments given to `run` matches the parameters of `fn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know that `params` is supposed to be the parameters of `fn`, but you can easily fix that but adding a generic parameter to associate the two:

```
type Params = { [key: string]: string };
type runner<P extends Params = Params> = (args: P) => void;

function run<P extends Params>(fn: runner<P>, params: P) {
    fn(params);
}
```

Now when you call your custom params function:

```
run(logHelloFromArgs, { hello: "123" });
```

It's inferred as

```
function run<{
    hello: string;
}>(fn: runner<{
    hello: string;
}>, params: {
    hello: string;
}): void
```

which is what we want.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXjEOm)

Comment: Thank you! Is there an alternative way to do the same without using generics?

Comment: No, I don't think so.